# "I undertake that ..." or "I undertake to ..."

Tags: british-english

Suppose I want to give an assurance. Which one is correct?

> 1. I undertake **that** I will give you your money as soon as I get home
> 2. I undertake **to** give you your money as soon as I get home

Comment: They are both correct.  You could substitute the verb 'promise' (or the verb 'swear') and they would still both work.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK And a lot of other verbs besides. *Decided, made up my mind, resolved, etc*.

Answer (score 1):

Both are fully grammatical and idiomatic; and if the subject of the embedded clause is the same as that of the matrix clause, synonymous.

It the subjects are different, then only the *that* form will work.